# Will dumpheap from jconsole contain jmx counters also?

Tags: jmx, jconsole

If I get a dumpheap using JConsole, will that contain jmx counters also ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dump, I did not find it. So, the answer is no. I'm exploring other ways to get a jmx dump.